# parentheses when calling a sub

Tags: script, vbscript

Trying to install a `.exe` using a `vbs`. I get an error can not use `parentheses when calling a sub` on `Line 11'. I am relatively new to VS and have no clue what they are talking about.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell,objFSO,strCommand,spath

    'INSTALL ESet ANTIVIRUS USING VBScript
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    spath = objShell.CurrentDirectory

    wscript.sleep 1800000
    If objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\Lightspeed Systems\User Agent") then
      objShell.LogEvent vbLogSuccess, sLogHeader & "Lightspeed is already installed." & VbCrLf & "Exit code: " & i
    End if

    If Not objFSO.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\Lightspeed Systems\User Agent") then

      If fso.FileExists(spath & "\Lightspeed\UserAgentx64 V2.1.14.exe") Then
        path = """" & spath & "\Lightspeed\UserAgentx64 V2.1.14.exe" & """ /passive /norestart /update-no"
          objShell.Run path, 1 ,True
        i = 0
       'INSTALL ESet ANTIVIRUS
        i = objShell.Run(path, 1 ,True)
      If (i = 0) Or (i = 3010) Then
        'WRITE EXIT CODE [0-success/3010-success&requires reboot] TO EVENTLOG
        objShell.LogEvent vbLogSuccess, sLogHeader & "Lightspeed installation completed successfully." & VbCrLf & "Exit code: " & i
      Else
        MsgBox "The installation of Lightspeed returned an error: " & i & VbCrLf & _
        "Please contact IT Support to report this error.", vbOKOnly
        objShell.LogEvent vbLogError, sLogHeader & "Installation returned failure code: " & VbCrLf & "Exit code: " & i
      End If

    Else
        WScript.Quit (1)
    End If

    set fso = Nothing
    set WSHShell = Nothing
    End if
```

Comment: It's probably this line `objShell.Run(path, 1 ,True)`. Either use `objShell.Run path, 1 ,True` or `Call objShell.Run(path, 1 ,True)`)

Comment: Updated code in first post. OK got a new error, `variable undefined "object"` on `line 11`.

Comment: `object.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn])` is merely a [syntax pattern from WSH reference](http://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp). Remove that line at all.

Comment: Ok updated code. Now I'm getting `is undefined 'spath'`on `line 14`

Comment: Ok, figured that out. Now I have no errors when it runs, but it doesn't return anything. It should tell me either it is installed already, installed it, or an error. I am getting nothing.

Comment: You need to debug your code to see how exactly it works.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288043/how-do-i-debug-a-stand-alone-vbscript-script